# How do you use clGetDeviceInfo to get CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS?

Tags: c++, opencl, gpgpu

How do you use clGetDeviceInfo to get CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS?
https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html

Answer (score 1):

The below function should accomplish this.

```
void print_address_device_bits(cl_device_id *mydevice)
{
    size_t size;
    cl_uint address_bits;
    clGetDeviceInfo(*mydevice, CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS, 0, NULL, &size);
    clGetDeviceInfo(*mydevice, CL_DEVICE_ADDRESS_BITS, size, &address_bits, NULL);
    printf("size: %lu ,, bits: %u\n", size, address_bits);
}
```

Any questions or comments?